# using xsl displays nothing

Tags: php, xml, xslt, formatting, domdocument

i'm trying to implement an xsl file to an xml doc. however when i do so, it displays nothing. if i remove the reference of the xsl from the xml file, the data at least is displayed.

this is the xsl code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
<div>
    <div style="background:red;"><xsl:value-of select="title"/></div>
    <div style="background:green;"><p><xsl:value-of select="introduction"/></p></div>
    <div style="background:blue;"><xsl:for-each select="verse">
            <div><xsl:value-of select="p"/></div> <br />
            <div><xsl:value-of select="trla"/></div> <br />
            <div><xsl:value-of select="trli"/></div> <br />
            </xsl:for-each>
    </div>
</div>

</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

the xml:

```
<root>
    <title></title>
    <introduction></introduction>
    <verse>
       <p></p>
       <trla></trla>
       <trli></trli>
    </verse>
</root>
```

and the html where the xml is being called through php:

```
<div id="display">
        <?php
        error_reporting(E_ALL);
        ini_set("display_errors", 1);

            $xmldoc = new DOMDocument();
            if(!file_exists('test.xml')){
              echo "Sorry this file does not exists!";
              exit();
            } else {
                $xmldoc->load('test.xml', LIBXML_NOBLANKS);


            $activities = $xmldoc->firstChild->firstChild;
            if($activities != null){
                    while($activities != null){
                                    ?>
                    <div id="xml">
                        <span>
                        <?php echo $activities->textContent ?> </li></ul></span> <br />

                    </div>
                                <?php
                                $activities = $activities->nextSibling;
                    }
                }
            }
         ?>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, there is no data in any of the nodes, so I would expect nothing to be displayed when `value-of` is called on them.

In addition, your template only matches the root element, you need to explicitly call the element with the name `root`, either in the template declaration, or the different selects.

Change the match rule to `<xsl:template match="/root">`.

Alternatively, the following will also work (provided you have data in the relevant nodes):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
<div>
    <div style="background:red;"><xsl:value-of select="root/title"/></div>
    <div style="background:green;"><p><xsl:value-of select="root/introduction"/></p></div>
    <div style="background:blue;"><xsl:for-each select="root/verse">
            <div><xsl:value-of select="p"/></div> <br />
            <div><xsl:value-of select="trla"/></div> <br />
            <div><xsl:value-of select="trli"/></div> <br />
            </xsl:for-each>
    </div>
</div>

</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: tried your suggestion. somehow it didn't work even when i explicitly called the element with the name `root`. the nodes are not empty.

Comment: @fuz3d - I tested your XML (with data) and my xsl here: http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/tryxslt.asp?xmlfile=cdcatalog&xsltfile=cdcatalog

Answer (score 1):

That's because inside the template the context node is the document root. Change the pattern matching to: `match select="/*"`